# Find the hidden checkboxes in Coypu

Tags: coypu

I'm try to create test for my Bootstrap project. I'm use [Coypu](https://github.com/featurist/coypu). But I ran into a some problem. I can't check my check-boxes. The problem is that I changed style form my check-box. And now standard Bootstraps check-boxes  is hidden. The new check-box is hidden inside standard pattern:

```
 <label> 
     <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: key, checked: $parent.selectedCatchments, attr: { id: key }" class="catchment-checkbox" />
 <span data-bind=" text: value, attr: { for: key }" class="lbl padding-8 openSans-Text catchment-checkbox-span"></span>
 </label>
```

The problem is that Coypu can't to find the hidden element on browser. And now I can't to check selected check-box or not.

This is standard check-box:

[image]

I turned off: opacity: 0 in CSS style. 
And this is new checkbox with the new style.

[image]

How can I check the number of checked items in Coypu?

I can add ConsideringInvisibleElements = true inside SetUp method, but this option will be works always for all Tests. How I can change value of ConsideringInvisibleElements option on true or false when I need inside test code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm find this variant:

```
var catchmentsCheckboxes = Browser.FindAllXPath("id('catchmentsColumn')/div[1]/div/label/input", null, new Coypu.Options { ConsiderInvisibleElements = true });
```

The first parameter: xPath to element;
The second parameter is can be null;
The third parameter is ConsideringInvisibleElements. And we can change value of this parameter on true or false.